# Angular scrolling to dynamically created element

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application where I retrieve data when the user clicks a button:

```
getJobNotes() {
  this.jobNoteService.getJobNotes()
    .subscribe(
      result => {
        this.jobNotes = result.jobNotes;
      }
    );
}
```

I would like to scroll into view an element that has a specific job note Id, ie, this may be the 5th element in a list of 10 as an example.

I have tried the following:

```
  this.selectedJobNoteId = result.selectedJobNoteId;
  let el = document.getElementById(this.selectedJobNoteId);
  el.scrollIntoView();
```

in this case my 'el' variable is undefined.

In my html I am setting the ID correctly:

```
<li *ngFor="let jobNote of jobNotes" id="{{jobNote.jobNoteId}}">
```

I have confirmed that the ID is set, and if I run document.getElementById with the correct ID in the chrome console then I get back the element - I suspect the issue is that the elements are dynamically created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a template variable to the list item:

```
<ul *ngIf="users">
  <li #user *ngFor="let userDetail of users">
    <h1>{{ userDetail.name }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ userDetail.username }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ userDetail.email }}</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then in the Component class, you could access the list-items using `ViewChildren`. Something like this:

```
@ViewChildren("user", { read: ElementRef }) renderedUsers: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

And then finally, you could use `scrollIntoView` on a `nativeElement` of any item to scroll to it:

```
getData() {
  this.http
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
      this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        const userToScrollOn = this.renderedUsers.toArray();
        userToScrollOn[this.indexToScrollTo].nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      }, 1000);
    });
}
```

I've used a `setTimeout` here coz, the list won't render as soon as you get the data. So there would be a slight delay before `renderedUsers` is initialized.

So in `ngOnDestroy` also make sure to clear the timeout by calling `clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);`

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-to-item-in-list-after-data-is-fetched-from-api?file=src/app/app.component.ts)  for your ref.